# Need assistance with C++ function to parse/display XML serialization

Tags: c++, xml, parsing, xml-parsing, xml-serialization

I need some help getting my XML serialization to work properly. Right now I have two functions that read my XML file, char by char. Right now they successfully detect and store elements as well as storing the content of the elements as a variable. I have the function print the hierarchy of the elements and they successfully show the contents that they contain.

My Problem: I can't get the function to correctly identify an end tag for the elements! For example, when the parsing gets to the elements end tag, it detects it as an element rather than the end of an element.

**Sorry for all the text and the length of the code. I'm trying to be as thorough as possible. Thanks in advanced!**

This is what is displayed when the code is compiled and ran. Notice hot there are elements that equal nothing:

```
XML.World.Item.name = silver key
XML.World.Item.properties.property = metal
XML.World.Item.properties.property = silver
XML.World.Item.properties = 
XML.World.Item.weight = 1
XML.World.Item.displayChar = )
XML.World.Item.value = 10
XML.World.Item.rarity = 5
XML.World.Item = 
XML.World.Creature.name = orc
XML.World.Creature.properties.property = orcish
XML.World.Creature.properties.property = humanoid
XML.World.Creature.properties = 
XML.World.Creature.level = 2
XML.World.Creature.maxHP = 15
XML.World.Creature.displayChar = o
XML.World.Creature = 
XML.World =
```

---

**My XML file is called world.xml and this is the XML code it contains:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<World>
<Item>
<name>silver key</name>
<properties>
<property>metal</property>
<property>silver</property>
</properties>
<weight>1</weight>
<displayChar>)</displayChar>
<value>10</value>
<rarity>5</rarity>
</Item>
<Creature>
<name>orc</name>
<properties>
<property>orcish</property>
<property>humanoid</property>
</properties>
<level>2</level>
<maxHP>15</maxHP>
<displayChar>o</displayChar>
</Creature>
</World>
```

---

**Here is my code being used - XMLSerialization.h, XMLSerialization.cpp, and main.cpp:**

**XMLSerialization.h**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>

class XMLSerialization {

public:
    virtual bool parseElement(std::istream & xmlFile, std::string hierarchy$
    virtual bool parseXML(std::istream & xmlFile);

private:
    //none
};
```

**XMLSerialization.cpp**

```
#include "XMLSerialization.h"
#include <string>

using namespace std;
bool XMLSerialization::parseElement(istream & xmlFile, string hierarchy){
    char c; // the character as we reach it
    string elementName;

    //reads char by char, checking for '>' at the end of the tag

    do {
        c = xmlFile.get();
        if (c != '>')
            elementName.push_back(c);
    }
    while (c != '>');

    string content; //holds the non-element content of the element

    while (true){
            c = xmlFile.get();
            if (c == '<'){
                    if (xmlFile.peek() == '/'){
                            xmlFile.get();
                            string endTag; //holds the end tag as its read

                            while(c != '>'){
                                    c = xmlFile.get();
                                    if (c != '>'){
                                            endTag.push_back(c);
                                    }
                            }

                            if (endTag != elementName){
                                cout<<"Tag name mismatch! "<<endTag<<
                                            " differs from "<<elementName
                                            <<"."<<endl;
                                    return false;
                            }

                            //output what is known. Where we are in the
                            //file, current element, and its content
                            cout<<hierarchy<<"."<<elementName<<" = "<<
                                    content<<endl;
                            return true;
                    }
                    else {
                            //read in '<' and was NOT an end tag. c is at
                            //the first char after < so function calls
                            //on itself again. Passing hierarchy and current
                            //element name so next element knows where it
                            //is in the xmlFile.
                            if (!parseElement(xmlFile, hierarchy + "." + el$
                                    return false;
                            }
                    }
            }

            else {
                    //c is not '<' so its content. Also ignores EOL
                    if (c != '\n'){
                                content.push_back(c);
                    }
            }
    }

    return true;
}



// checks for a valid XML Header
bool XMLSerialization::parseXML(istream & xmlFile){
    char c; // char to hold the character as we reach it

    //get character while the character != '<'
    do {
            c = xmlFile.get();
    }
    while (c != '<');

    //checks the character after the '<'
    if (xmlFile.get() != '?'){
            cout<<"Invalid XML Header! Does not begin with '<?'"<<endl;
            return false;
    }
   //continues through header look for '?'
    do {
            c = xmlFile.get();
    }
    while (c != '?');

    // checks for the header ending with ?>
    if (xmlFile.get() != '>'){
            cout<<"Invalid XML Header! Does not end with '?>'"<<endl;
            return false;
    }

    // go through character until the first tag after the header
    do {
            c = xmlFile.get();
    }
    while (c != '<');

    // at the first character after the opening '<' of the tag
    // call parseElement
    return parseElement(xmlFile, "XML");
}
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include "XMLSerialization.h"
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char * argv[]){
    cout<<"________________________"<<endl;
    cout<<"XML TESTING"<<endl<<"________________________"<<endl<<endl;
    ifstream xmlFile;
    xmlFile.open("world.xml");
    XMLSerialization test;
    test.parseXML(xmlFile);
    xmlFile.close();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Which OS are you developing for? I very much agree with what Michael and Steven say: use a library. Depending on the OS you are targetting there should be something already available (e.g. under Windows there is MSXML) - besides various third-party libraries

Answer (score 2):

Please for the love of all that is holy, use a proper XML parser. You will be glad you did. I highly recommend [libxml2](http://xmlsoft.org).

Comment: I recommend Rapidxml. http://rapidxml.sourceforge.net/ You don't want to roll your own, really.

Comment: Part of this project is writing a custom XML parser unfortunately =/

Comment: You can't call it an XML parser if you are not handling DTDs, entity references, proper character encoding detection, processing instructions, CDATA sections, namespaces... at best you can say this is an "XML-like" format :)

Comment: Lol yes. Its an XML-Like parsing function. That being said, any suggestions?

Comment: Well, part of your problem is that `parseElement` uses `c` uninitialised in the first while loop.

Comment: @MichaelDay, that way it automatically enters the while loop. The first line in the while sets c to the next character.

Comment: Blah, uninitialised variables can have any value whatsoever, and can't be trusted. Set it explicitly to a character if that's what you mean, or replace the while with a do-while loop.

Comment: By the way, the actual output looks fine, as the Item, Creature, and World elements don't have any non-whitespace text content.

Comment: Ok thanks, I'll change it. Yeah I'm just trying to figure out how to go about ignoring where its printing the chains that don't equal anything.